# How to find files containing two strings in different lines

Tags: grep, find

A real example is: I have a Python file `util.py`, and I changed one of the function name from `foo` to `bar`. There might be other files using `foo` as function name and they are irrelevant.

I want to update all the Python files in the project from `foo` to `bar`. So I would like to do a search on files for imports such as:

```
import project.path.util
```

or

```
from project.path.util import foo
```

and any calls to `foo` such as one starting with:

```
foo(
```

The solution has to be whitespace tolerant.
I can search each of them using `grep` but I am uncertain about the combined search. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: edited your question to eliminate potential confusion between literal text you would like to search for and their regex representations. If you disagree roll back - thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU tools:

```
grep -rlZ --include='*.py' -e 'import project.path.util' \
                           -e 'from project.path.util import.*\bfoo\b' . |
  xargs -r0 sed -i 's/\bfoo\b/bar/g'
```

This works by asking `grep` to

1. search recursively (`-r`)
2. outputting names of matching files (`-l`)
3. separated by NUL instead of LF (`-Z`)
4. considering only files ending in '.py' (`--include='*.py'`)

and asking `sed` to perform the replacement in-place (`-i`) in all matching files, if there are any (`xargs -r`).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are in the directory that you want to search from (it matches any subdirectory also):

```
 for i in `find . -type f -name '*.py' -exec grep -lr 'foo' {} +`; do sed -i 's/foo/bar/' $i; done
```

Edit:

In order to avoid matching functions containing the characters, like "damned_fools" we can improve it with \b to match word boundaries:

```
for i in `find . -type f -name '*.py' -exec grep -lr 'foo' {} +`; do sed -i 's/\bfoo\b/bar/' $i; done
```

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032023/sed-whole-word-search-and-replace

Comment: What if one of the OP's functions is named `damned_fools`?

Answer (score 0):

This should do.

`/g` will substitute all instances of `foo` with `bar`

```
find <Project root dir> -type f -exec sed -i "{}" -e 's/foo/bar/g' \;
```

If you want to restrict the change to *.py files only :

```
find <Project root dir> -type f -name "*.py" -exec sed -i "{}" -e 's/foo/bar/g' \;
```

If there are instances of foo that should not be replaced, you can restrict to 4 cases:

- import **foo**
- from module import **foo**
- def **foo**
- **foo**(

But not

- damned_foo(
- damnedfoo(
- damned1foo(
- damned-foo(

Then the command would look like this :

```
foo="foo";bar="bar";find <Project root dir>  -type f -exec sed -i "{}" \
-r -e "s/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]$foo\(/$bar\(/g" -e "s/def $foo/def $bar/g" \
-e "s/import $foo/import $bar/g" \;
```

Comment: What if one of the OP's functions is named `damned_fools`

Comment: @1_CR: Sorry not sure if the name chosen in your example is for a laugh or not.I don't see a problem in terms of regex with sed tho. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: The OP's trying to change a function name in the file that defines the function and propagate the change to other files that contain references to the function. A blanket `s/foo/bar/g` replace would play badly with this situation in case the text `foo` is itself embedded inside other function names